# Why does this code return an array full of zeroes?

Tags: java

This code just pumps out an array of 0s. I have no idea why. It's bound to be something simple, so I apologize in advance, but it's very early here and I'm falling asleep on my keyboard. It's just a project for class (I'm new to Java, but I've been doing c++ for a little while) and I'll look at it again when I get home later, but any help would still be great.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner inpt = new Scanner(System.in);          

    int[] topTen = new int[10];
    int foo = 0, bogie = 0;
    int lo = 0, hi = 0, swit = 0;

    for(int b = 0; b < 15; b++){
        lo = inpt.nextInt();

        hi = inpt.nextInt();

        for(int c = 0; c < topTen.length; c++) {    
            if((hi-lo) > topTen[c]) {
                foo = topTen[c];
                for(int d = c + 1; d < topTen.length; d++) {
                    swit = (swit == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                    switch(swit) {
                        case 0:
                            foo = topTen[d];
                            topTen[d] = bogie;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            bogie = topTen[d];
                            topTen[d] = foo;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

After this ran, `topTen` is full of `0`s

Comment: have you tried debugger?

Comment: Side note: you seem to be using an `int` like a boolean. Chance `swit` to a  boolean, then you can do `swit = !swit` and `if(swit) { ...} else {...}`.

Comment: I realize that I should use swit as a boolean, but my class hasn't been taught switch/case or the ternary operator (among many other things) so I like to throw them around.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the only place you assign a value to an element of the array is in :

```
topTen[d] = foo;
```

But the only time you assign a value to `foo` is :

```
foo = topTen[c];
```

and

```
foo = topTen[d];
```

Therefore both `foo` and the elements of the array remain 0.

Correction: you also assign `bogie` to an element of the array and vice versa, but that doesn't change anything, since `bogie` also remains 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here

int foo = 0;
int bogie = 0;

and you are only adding this two values to the array int[] topTen.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code, the only non-zero number you are working with is `Rlo = 99`.  Within your for-loops you are only working with numbers that equal zero, so of course you will get an array consisting of only zero.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten home now, and I'm much more awake. I've looked over my code and I got it working great. I had forgotten to assign `topTen[c]` as `(hi-lo)`, and haven't realized it until now. Thank you.